# Can't start up python3 on embeded system

Tags: python

I'm building python 3.4.4 on a mips CPU running linux using the cross-compiler method on Ubuntu.

Now I have successfully built the python3 and installed it on the mips system.

But when running python3 on the mips system, it just can't start up the python3 shell.

```
/lib/python3.4 # echo $PYTHONPATH
/lib/python3.4/
/lib/python3.4 # echo $PYTHONHOME
/bin
/lib/python3.4 # python3 -v
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import imp # builtin
import sys # builtin
# installing zipimport hook
# installed zipimport hook
# possible namespace for /lib/python3.4/encodings
import 'encodings' # None
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Current thread 0x00000400 (most recent call first):
Aborted
/lib/python3.4 #
```

I checked the python source code, and find the error is reported from the function _PyCodec_Lookup() in Python-3.4.4\Python\codecs.c.

```
/* Next, scan the search functions in order of registration */
    args = PyTuple_New(1);
    if (args == NULL)
        goto onError;
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(args,0,v);

    len = PyList_Size(interp->codec_search_path);
    if (len < 0)
        goto onError;
    if (len == 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_LookupError,
                        "no codec search functions registered: "
                        "can't find encoding");
        goto onError;
    }
```

Anyone encounter this problem before or is there anything wrong with the cross-compiler building?

Thanks